# sql calculate total nights*rate+extras ? sqlzoo

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently stuck at task 7 http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Guest_House_Assessment_Medium task is Including Extras. Calculate the total bill for booking 5128 including extras.

This is what i got

```
select sum(b.nights*r.amount+e.amount)
from booking b inner join rate r 
ON room_type_requested=r.room_type
and
b.occupants=r.occupancy
inner join extra e on b.booking_id=e.booking_id
where b.booking_id=5128
```

answer I get with extra is 451.80 which is obviously wrong. If I only calculate amount for room price for all nights like these

```
select sum(b.nights*r.amount)
from booking b inner join rate r 
ON room_type_requested=r.room_type
and
b.occupants=r.occupancy

where b.booking_id=5128
```

I get 216.00 which seems correct for this booking for 3 nights without extras. However the correct answer suggested under task is 118.56 with extras. How can it be?

Can someone please explain to me why it is 118.56 and what I am doing wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: Why the mysqli tag? (I see no php code here.)

Comment: `select b.nights*r.amount+e.amount as total`

Comment: now i have two results 
total
234.00
217.00

Comment: Or maybe `select b.nights*r.amount+SUM(e.amount) as total` if you have multiple extras rows

Comment: Nights is stored in booking table, amount for extras is stored in extra table and room rate is stored i rate table.

Comment: Obviously the answer in the question is incorrect. I have no idea how they got .56

Answer (score 1):

You should calculate the bill for room and extra bill seperately, and then sum them together.

```
select bill_1 + bill_2
from
(select booking_id, sum(amount*nights) as bill_1 from 
booking b JOIN rate r ON b.room_type_requested = r.room_type and b.occupants = r.occupancy
group by booking_id
having booking_id = 5128) t1

join

(select booking_id, sum(amount) as bill_2 from extra
group by booking_id
having booking_id = 5128) t2

on t2.booking_id = t1.booking_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just been going through these tutorials and this is one of a handful of incorrect answers I've been finding on SQLZOO, hence finding this post on SO as I tried to work out what I was doing wrong.

I thought it was worth highlighting that for instances like this, where you're trying to work out if you disagree with the site's answer, you can enter much simpler queries to get at the underlying data. In this case it does show that the site's answer is wrong.

Q: How many nights at what rate?

```
SELECT amount, nights
FROM booking JOIN rate ON
    (room_type=room_type_requested AND occupancy=occupants)
WHERE booking_id=5128 

Result = 3 nights at 72.00 = 216.00
```

Q: What were the extras?

```
SELECT * FROM extra WHERE booking_id=5128

Result is two items (breakfast and phone calls), 18.00 + 1.80 = 19.80
```

So the correct answer according to the data is 216.00 + 19.80 = 235.80.

Answer (score 0):

Using the logic, the SQL should be:

```
select sum(r2.amount * b1.nights)+ sum(e3.amount) as total 
from booking b1
inner join rate  r2
on r2.room_type = b1.room_type_requested
and r2.occupancy = b1.occupants
left join (select booking_id, sum(amount) as amount 
           from extra
           group by booking_id) e3
on e3.booking_id = b1.booking_id
where b1.booking_id = 5128
```

Returns 235.80

Comment: If you join on extras you will have dups. This is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Output will be `235.80` however site has listed the wrong output `118.56`.

```
SELECT sum(b.nights * r.amount) +
  (SELECT sum(e.amount)
   FROM extra AS e
   WHERE e.booking_id = b.booking_id)
FROM booking AS b
INNER JOIN rate AS r ON r.occupancy = b.occupants
AND r.room_type = b.room_type_requested
WHERE b.booking_id = 5128
GROUP BY b.booking_id;
```